# How can I fit images in full height columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to achieve something like this: http://weprob.aw-theme.com/home_one/index.html

This example is using `owl-carousel` but I don't need that. I just want to fit the images inside the 3 full height columns I have, without any padding or spaces between them.

And when viewed on a smaller screen, I would like the images to retain their full height dimensions.

This is what I have so far

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="assets/images/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="assets/images/slide2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="assets/images/slide4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is fairly simple

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I added `overflow: hidden` because I can see the horizontal scrollbar.

However, this is how it's coming out

[image: Full Screen]

And this is how it looks when I resize the browser

[image: Responsive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood correctly , you want something like this ? see snippet below or fiddle here > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24008/)**

first i made the columns equal in height, because by default they have the height of the content inside them, and if you use `imgs` with different sizes, to `cols` will not be equal in  height. this was done with a simple JQ

then , because `img.responsive` has some default css from bootstrap, i had to overwrite it.

also the columns have their default CSS that need to be changed.

as a conclusion, if you want something like this, i don't think you need to use bootstrap. but that's your choice. maybe i didn't understand exactly what you want.

```js
var highest = 0;
        $('.col-md-4').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highest){  
                highest = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.col-md-4').height(highest);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-responsive{ 
height:100%;
width:auto;
max-width:none
}
.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 { 
width:33.33%;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="http://beerhold.it/200/200" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="http://beerhold.it/250/250" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="http://beerhold.it/500/500" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I am looking for, but at the moment, I'm having a weird problem. When I open the developer's tools, I see the stylesheet's link `file:///C:/Users/George/Desktop/Designs/design1/vendor/bootstrap/css/dist/css/bootstrap.css` but I don't have any a `dist` directory and I am using `bootstrap.min.css` so the changes you offered, aren't being reflected on the site.

Comment: well look where you called that link and change it. in the <head> section probably

Comment: Yup, I fixed that. and I think your code works. Thank you.

Comment: One last question, what if I only want to make these changes on the first section with id `intro` how can I do that without having the same effect everywhere?

Comment: well put `#intro` in css before everything you want to change. for example `#intro img.responsive{....}` and then `#intro .col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12{....}`